# Twilio API in loop continue sending messages even if a phone is invalid

Tags: api, twilio, twilio-php

I have an array of phone numbers which I am looping over and sending a text message to.

Occasionally a number may be invalid and an error is thrown from Twilio. I know I can comment out the echo in the catch but if an exception is still thrown I need to my loop to continue. Should I remove the try catch entirely?

```
      foreach($filterphones as $key => $value){

         $account_sid = 'xxx'; 
         $auth_token = 'xxx'; 
         $client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 


         try {
             $message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
                 'From' => "+16XXXXXXXXX", 
                 'To' => $value, 
                 'Body' => $body,
             ));
         }catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
             //echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      }
```

Comment: Looks to me like that would work as expected. What are you finding happens right now?

Comment: @Anagio -- did you solve your issue? I'm in a similar situation and would like to know what you did.

Comment: @LargeGlasses follow the suggestion from `hairys` at https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/203 the solution was to replace ca.certs or add to ca.certs on your server. If you replace it, in php.ini you specify the location of the new certificate file to be used. Let me know if that helps